# Operações com filas lineares, movendo um elemento para primeiro da fila

Tags: c

Preciso de um algorítmo que manipule uma lista linear do tipo FILA. (Em PASCAL, ou pode ser feita em pseudo-código, ou C, ou o que for preferível).

O algoritmo deve pegar uma elemento da fila, retirá-lo e inserir este elemento no inicio. O vetor que gurda a fila deve ser reorganizado (ja que se você tirar o elemento do meio, você quebra a fila).

A FILA é circular, ela da volta em sí mesma, vou deixar abaixo a estrutura da pilha feita em PASCAL:

```
type
ElementosF = integer; //tipo de dado que a fila ira receber
fila = record
              memoria:array[1..TAMF] of ElementosF; //memoria da fila
              final,inicio,total:integer; //ultimo, primeiro, total de elemento da fila
             end;
```

A dúvida é, como faço isso? Tentei de diversas formas, e todas falhei... Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer um algoritmo desse tipo. Aconselho você a ver as diferentes formas de implementação que eu coloquei aqui e tentar fazer o seu próprio código.

Fila em `C`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 5 // numero maximo de elementos na fila

// cria uma fila vazia
int comeco = 0;   // comeco da fila
int tamanho = 0;  // tamanho da fila (numero de elementos)
int queue[MAX];   // vetor da fila

void inserir( int );    // inserir elementos no fim da fila
void remover( void );   // remover elementos do comeco da fila

int main(void)
{
    int i; // contador

    inserir(1);
    inserir(10);
    inserir(100);
    inserir(1000);
    remover();
    inserir(6);
    remover();
    inserir(60);

    //// mostra fila na tela ////
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        printf("fila[%i] = %i\n", i, queue);

//  system("pause"); // comente esta linha se for rodar no linux
    return ( 0 );

} // fim main    


void inserir( int elemento )
{
    //// checa se a fila esta cheia ////
    if( tamanho == MAX )
        printf("\nfila cheia\n");

    else {
        //// converte os valores virtuais (tamanho e comeco) para o valor real utilizando o operador modulo ////
        queue[ ((comeco + tamanho) % MAX) ] = elemento; 
        //// incrementa tamanho da fila (elemento foi inserido) ////
        tamanho ++; 
    } 

} // fim funcao


void remover(void)
{
    //// checa se a fila esta vazia ////
    if( tamanho == 0 )
        printf("\nfila vazia\n");

    else {
        //// apaga o primeiro elemento da fila deslocando o ponteiro do comeco para proximo elemento ////
        comeco ++;
        //// decrementa o contador de tamanho (um valor foi removido) ////
        tamanho --;
    }

} // fim funcao
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/berW10)

Na internet tem vários algoritmos prontos, veja esse [site](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2014/05/Filas-em-C-Como-Programar-Tutorial-Estrutura-de-Dados-Dinamica-Queue.html). Ele inclusive detalha cada função. Nesse [site](http://br.ccm.net/faq/10219-as-filas-em-linguagem-c), também possui outra implementação.

Comment: Boa implementação. Não estava muito convencido, fiz alguns testes aqui e não achei bug. :)